# Порядок перебора записей БД при выполнении запроса SELECT

Tags: база-данных, select

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каком порядке производится перебор записей таблицы БД при выполнении запроса SELECT? То есть, в каком порядке в результирующем массиве будут расположены данные, получаемые селектом без использования ORDER BY?

Например, есть таблица table, в которой 4 столбца и 12 строк (записей):

12 Декабрь 31 очень холодно

11 Ноябрь 30 холодно

10 Октябрь 31 холодно

09 Сентябрь 30 Прохладно

08 Август 31 жарко

07 Июль 31 жара

06 Июнь 30 жарко

05 Май 31 тепло

04 Апрель 30 тепло

03 Март 31 Прохладно

02 Февраль 29 Холодно

01 Январь 31 Очень холодно

Если я пишу запрос `SELECT`month`FROM`table`WHERE`days`=31`, в каком порядке я получу результат? 
Спасибо!